# Get data from api with multiple parameters in link

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to get data from an API in swift using alamofire.

The link is like this:

`www.something.com?date1=2015-06-04&date2=2015-06-04&id=1`

How do I pass the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dictionary of parameters ....and just passed it  like

```
let param = [  "date1" : "2015-06-04",
                "date2" : "2015-06-04",
                "id" : 1
             ]

//and passed it in request
Alamofire.request(.GET, "www.something.com", parameters:param)
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the problem or error with this method???i'll help you for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["date1": "2015-06-04", "date2":"2015-06-04", "id":1])
         .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                     println(request)
                     println(response)
                     println(error)
                   }
```

Comment: ahhh...just fraction short to posted an answer...you are just few second quick...:)

Comment: i think both of the answers are right...so +1 for you from my side :)

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters into the `NSMutableDictionary` and than append dictionary with URL string. It's easy for me.

I have example in Objective C. May be it's Usefull to you.

```
NSMutableDictionary * dictParam = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictParam setObject:txtMessage.text forKey:@"Desctiprion"];
[dictParam setObject:type forKey:@"Type"];

NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com"];

NSString *strParameter = @"";
NSString *strData;
if (dictParam != nil) {
    strParameter = [self encodeDictionaryToString:dictParam];
    strData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@",strUrl,strParameter];
}else{
    strData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strUrl];
}

NSString *strURL = [strData stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
```

Comment: i have example in Objective C not in Swift